# How to use data stored in a variable located in a seperate file?

Tags: java, class, object, methods, call

I have two files. One file counts the number of listed events I have in a text file and stores the number of events into the variable "count". I want to then use the value in this variable to do computation in a second file. How do I do this? Do I have to create an object of the class in my first file and then reference it? I need an example please, I cannot seem to get this to work. Here is what I have tried.

My first file:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
    public class EventCounter {
        public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException{

            Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("event.txt"));
            int count = 0;
            while (file.hasNextLine()) {
                count++;
                file.nextLine();
            }

            System.out.println(count); //test
        }
    }
```

My Second file:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class ReadEventFile {

    private String path;
    public ReadEventFile(String file) {
        path = file;
    }

    public String[] OpenFile() throws IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr); 

        EventCounter method = new EventCounter(); //make object?
        String[] dataTable = new String[count];

        int i;
        for (i=0; i<count; i++) { //Why count does not exist?
        }
```

My second file does not know that count is a variable from my first file :-(

Comment: April fools..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have your process flow backwards. The class with the `main` method will be created and run by the JVM - therefore it's your entry point.

Your `ReadEventFile` class therefore needs to be told the `count` when it is created. Simply add it to the constructor:

```
public static class ReadEventFile {

    private final File eventFile;
    private final int count;

    public ReadEventFile(final int count, final File eventFile) {
        this.eventFile = eventFile;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String[] openFile() throws IOException {
        String[] dataTable = new String[count];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        }
        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

Now your `EventCounter` needs to create a `ReadEventFile` instance once it knows the `count` and call the `openFile` method on it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    final File eventFile = new File("event.txt");
    int count = 0;
    try (Scanner file = new Scanner(eventFile)) {
        while (file.hasNextLine()) {
            count++;
            file.nextLine();
        }
    }
    final ReadEventFile readEventFile = new ReadEventFile(count, eventFile);
    final String[] dataTable = readEventFile.openFile();
}
```

The `ReadEventFile` does it's work and then returns the `String[]` back to your `EventCounter`.

You don't close any of your resources when you are done with them. This is asking for trouble. I have added a Java 7 try-with-resources around your `Scanner` in the `EventCounter`.

The design of this program does seem a little odd. There is no logical reason why the `EventCounter` should be the entry point to the application. I would recommend you create a `BootStrap` class that holds the `main` method and is the entry point that then calls both the `EventCounter` and the `ReadEventFile`.

Further, the `openFile` method on the `ReadEventFile` class isn't well named - it does more than that. Maybe `processEventFile` or something along those lines would be more appropriate.

Comment: I will work on that. Sorry, this is my second day of programming. I am just trying to get a handle on things. I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

your first Program

```
package farzi;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
    public class EventCounter {
        public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
        {
            EventCounter object = new EventCounter();
            System.out.println(object.returnCount());
        }

        public int returnCount() throws FileNotFoundException
        {
            Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("event.txt"));
            int count = 0;
            while (file.hasNextLine()) {
                count++;
                file.nextLine();
            }
            System.out.println(count); //test
            return count;
        }
    }
```

your second program

```
package farzi;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class ReadEventFile 
{

    private String path;
    public ReadEventFile(String file) 
    {
        String path = file;
    }

    public String[] OpenFile() throws IOException {

        EventCounter eventCounterObject = new EventCounter();
        int countLocal = eventCounterObject.returnCount();

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr); 

        EventCounter method = new EventCounter(); //make object?
        String[] dataTable = new String[countLocal];

        int i;
        String[] textData = null;
        for (i=0; i<countLocal; i++) { //Why count does not exist?

            textData[i] = textReader.readLine();
        }
        return textData;

    }

}
```

Comment: This is _very odd_ - how is it supposed to work. The application starts, `main` is called. Then what? Where is the other class (`ReadEventFile`) even called from.

Comment: I think I see how the process works now. Thanks, with this example I can proceed.

Comment: @bmorris591 : i have called the object of first class in to second class to use return counter method , and main method is just for demo in case you check executing the first class only